# If you are sure a user is vote-bombing you unfairly is there anything you can do about it?

Tags: support, bad-user-behavior

I recently voted down a user that likes to make unfounded claims and has answered several questions with monologues about something else (as I've mentioned to him in the comments). Then I discovered I had 4 down-votes in a very short timespan on questions and answers that the community thought were good. Upon investigating I found that this user has 4 recently cast negative votes today, and it's the only negative votes hes ever cast.

Is there some mechanic in place for dealing with that type of behavior, or should I just move on in life? :)

Comment: I have looked at the situation in more detail. Unfortunately, there is nothing we can do here. If he does cast more downvotes on you though, the system will likely automatically reverse all of them. He's very close to the threshold where actions can be taken.

Comment: Oh that's okay. I don't really care about getting my points back, I just wanted to make you aware of the bad behavior from that user for the future if he feels a need to be disruptive again. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an automated script running every 24 hours that will detect unusual voting patterns and it will usually revert serial downvoting of users.

If the votes are not reverted in 1-2 days, just flag one of the relevant posts for moderator attention, explain the situation, and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. :)

Comment: If the system detects a voting fraud, it'll be reset at 0:00 UTC.